# Given a QR code for a TOTP secret, how would I format an argument to openconnect so that I didn't get prompted for a challenge / response

Tags: command-line, vpn, two-factor-authentication

I have a QR code for setting up, say google authenitcator to generate TOTP codes.  I've viewed the text value of the QR code and it looks like:

`otpauth://totp/<user>@<host>?secret=A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8`

openconnect vpn client claims I can pass in the secret to it as a command line arg but I've tried just

`--token-secret=A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8`

but that doesn't appear to work?  Anyone with experience of this out there who can adivse?

Answer (score 3):

You can connect using following:

```
openconnect HOSTNAME --user=USERNAME --passwd-on-stdin --token-mode=totp --token-secret=sha1:base32:TOKEN
```

EDIT: Added more information as per comment.

You are missing the

```
-token--mode=totp
```

You can use the command I mentioned on top to connect.

```
--passwd-on-stdin
```

is used to enter the password (unmasked I must say) on stdin just after executing the command.

Also, make sure you provide encoding and hashing algorithm used with token secret. Since you mentioned you are using google authenticator which defaults to base32 and sha1.

```
sha1:base32:TOKEN
```

Lastly, it works for me over linux and mac but not over windows.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it was written.

Comment: @music2myear updated to reflect more information according to question.

Comment: it works. Thank you.